# How write a program that takes the marks of user as input?

Tags: java, input

How can I write a program that takes marks as user input? If marks are greater then 60 the program should display "Great, you have passed the course", else the program should print "Sorry, you have failed he course".

// I wish to clarify, because I did not understand how to write a program like this and thank you:)

Comment: For basic programming tasks, Rosetta Code is a good starting point. It provides examples of user input (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/User_input/Text#Java) and command line output (http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hello_world/Text#Java) in different languages including Java. There's even a code snippet that reads two integers from command line and compares them in Java: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Integer_comparison#Java

Comment: You can read any introductory java book to code this simple program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I would use the [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class for Java to take in users input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

.........

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int mark = sc.nextInt(); // this will get input from user
System.out.println("Marks: " + mark);
```